# Removing elements of list using parent/child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-lists

I'm looking to dynamically remove li elements from several connected ul lists.  Right now I am assigning 'dblclick' event behaviors by using `$("#sortable1").children().on('dblclick',function() {...})`

The items in #sortable1 will be moved to other lists (#sortable2, #sortable3, etc) by the user.

When a list item is double clicked, a dialog box pops up asking if the user would like to delete it.  If the user says yes, I want the list item to be removed from whatever list it is in.  I am trying to do it using something like:

```
$($(this).parent().childNodes[$(this).index()]).remove()
```

But that doesn't work.

Advice?

Comment: Show us how the function's working, how are the copied/moved list-items connected to each other? Class-name, a `data-*` attribute? Do you have a live demo we can see, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar?

Comment: so you want to remove the item that was double clicked on? wouldn't $(this).remove() inside of your handler do it?

Comment: I think he wants it to happen after the popup toggle is clicked.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte that should be ok, he just needs to store $(this) when double clicked then use it later. Oh maybe he wants to remove it from several ul and not jsut the clicked one. Need to see more markup

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? I think you might be over complicating things. This is a simple example of what I believe you are doing: http://jsbin.com/ixemuw/2/edit

Comment: Huangsim - brilliant!!  I don't know why I was overthinking it so much - that was all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
var showPopup = function( elem ){
  //show your popup with a function like this, as i assume it already does...      
  $( '#delete_toggle' ).one( 'click', function(){
    elem.remove();
  });
};

$("#sortable1").children().on('dblclick',function(){
  showPopup( $(this) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the element that was clicked on, you just use this in the event handler:

```
$(this).remove();
```

or if you've saved the element reference to a variable `elem`, it would be this:

```
$(elem).remove();
```

You are trying to make it way more complicated than need be.  The jQuery `.remove()` method looks at who its current parent is and takes care of all that for you.